# Microsoft Test Manager (on VS Enterprise 2015)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, microsoft-test-manager

We are using VS Enterprise 2015 and Microsoft Test Manger on Windows 7 OS 64-bit VM.

We are having following issues.

Problem: Unable to connect to test agent in ready status from the Lab Environment. "Microsoft Environment Viewer could not connect to the machine" error is displayed. See issue snapshot attached here.

Steps Undertaken for the installation of Test Controller/ Test Agent

•Installed Microsoft Test Controller 2013 Successfully

•Test Controller is configured to the on-premise Team Foundation Server Team Project Collection

•Installed Microsoft Test Agent Successfully 2013 Update 5 (Interactive Process)

•Test Agent is registered to the Test Controller

•Test Agent is available and in Ready status

•Test agent service member is configured to be a member of Team TestAgentService

•Test controller is a member of the Project Collection Administrator group.

•Test controller user is an admin user in the Test Agent machines

•We are able to remote desktop to the test agent machines, but unable to connect from Lab environment.

Will appreciate your prompt help or any pointers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzTHd.png)
Regards,

Rajesh

Comment: This is not Microsoft Support Center. Here is a community where you post your code when you are having troubles through coding. Consider close this question and ask microsoft support team about it.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already posted the same on MSDN social site. no response yet from there. hence, seeking some help here.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9519096e-573a-4f90-a8cc-f247fa5a01cd/microsoft-test-manager-vs-enterprise-2015?forum=vsmantest